# Get data from javascript array using a value of key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array 
`myArray = [{'id':'73','data':'SampleData 1'},{'id':'45','data':'SampleData 2'}];`

By providing the `id` of this array as `45` how can i get the `SampleData 2` as `data`.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a for loop and an if statement? Do you know how to loop through an array?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many ways to do this, and libraries like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) provide methods to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. Test the snippet and you will see the alert run. There are better ways to do this, but this method is simple and doesn't require anything but javascript.

```js
data = [{"id": 45, "thing": "asdf"}, {"id": 32, "thing": "jkl"}];

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].id == 45) {
    alert("Found the object with id of 45, alerting 'thing' property");
    alert(data[i].thing);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By filtering the array for the ID you want, you'll get back an array with only objects matching the filter.

```
const [myItem] = myArray.filter(item => item.id === 45);
```

In the above code, `myItem` will be `{'id':'45','data':'SampleData 2'}`.  You could go a step further and do:

```
const [{ data: myItemsData }] = myArray.filter(item => item.id === 45);
```

In this situation, `myItemsData` will be `'SampleData 2'`.

As @torazaburo points out, you can use:

```
const { data: myItemsData } = myArray.find(item => item.id === 45);
```

Comment: Why are you using `filter` instead of `find`?

Comment: @torazaburo old habit.  [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) has compatibility back further than [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Any environment supporting destructuring assignment will have `find`.

Comment: Definitely.  Just that i've been using filter for much longer than find, so I tend to think of it first.  You're correct, however.